# Android:How to set Multiple button,edittext,etc

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How to set two or more buttons in horizontally and like that all comes in order of vertical form.
Please tell coding in xml.

Comment: Have you actually tried it yourself, or were you hoping we'd just... do it for you? For free?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put them in a linearlayout and set the orientation to horizontal

```
 <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/login_selectionButtonGroup"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Button 1"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Button 2"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, but can i get another buttons exactly under button1 and button2?

Comment: Yea, duplicating the layout in the answer should then have button1 and button2 and button3 and button 4 should be placed underneath

Comment: @Keyser cheers, fixed it now must have deleted it by mistake when tidying it up